# List object names in mustache

Tags: mustache

I can change the JSON structure, but I do not know the tag names, how many tags there will be, nor if they will have values or how many values.

JSON:

```
{
  "tags":{
    "some_tag":[
      null
    ],
    "another_tag":[
      "value1",
      "value2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Mustache:

???

Expected result:

```
<ul>
  <li>some_tag:</li>
  <li>
    another_tag:
    <ol>
      <li>value1</li>
      <li>value2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would not have closed this. I get what's being asked here. In fact, I wish I knew the answer.